# The image inside a button is not displayed on click

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to find out the mistake I'm making to display the image inside the button, please help me with that. Thank You.

```js
let gameTitle = document.createElement('div');
gameTitle.className = 'gameTitle';
gameTitle.innerHTML = '<b>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</b>';
gameTitle.style.fontSize = '20px';
gameTitle.style.wordSpacing = '8px';
gameTitle.style.textAlign = 'center';
document.body.appendChild(gameTitle);

const choices = [
  '<img src="images/rockgame.jpg" alt = "rock" >',
  '<img src="images/papergame.jpg" alt = "paper" >',
  '<img src="images/scissorsgame.jpg" alt = "scissors">',
  // 'rock',
  // 'paper',
  // 'scissors',
];

let myPick = choices.innerHTML;

let buttonContainer = document.createElement('div');
buttonContainer.id = 'buttonContainer';
document.body.appendChild(buttonContainer);

const clickChoice = (show) => {
  const myChoice = show.innerHTML;
  const compChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  displayResults(myChoice, compChoice);
  console.log(show);
};

choices.forEach((choice) => {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className = 'button';
  button.innerHTML = choice;
  button.addEventListener('click', clickChoice);
  buttonContainer.appendChild(button);
});

let scoreContainer = document.createElement('div');
scoreContainer.id = 'scoreContainer';
document.body.append(scoreContainer);

let myChoice = document.createElement('div');
myChoice.classList.add('results', 'mine');
myChoice.innerHTML = 'You -' + myChoice;
scoreContainer.appendChild(myChoice);

let compChoice = document.createElement('div');
compChoice.classList.add('results', 'comp');
compChoice.innerHTML = 'Computer - ' + compChoice;
scoreContainer.appendChild(compChoice);

let result = document.createElement('div');
result.classList.add('results', 'final');
result.innerHTML = 'Score - ';
scoreContainer.appendChild(result);

const displayResults = (myChoice, compChoice) => {
  switch (myChoice + compChoice) {
    case 'scissorspaper':
    case 'rockscissors':
    case 'paperrock':
      scoreContainer.innerHTML = 'You' + myChoice + 'Computer' + compChoice;
      break;

    case 'papersciccors':
    case 'scissorsrock':
    case 'rockpaper':
      scoreContainer.innerHTML = 'You' + myChoice + 'Computer' + compChoice;
      break;
    case 'paperpaper':
    case 'scissorsscissors':
    case 'rockrock':
      scoreContainer.innerHTML = 'Even';

      break;
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.gameTitle {
  display: flexbox;
}
.button {
  border: blue 1px solid;
  outline: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: 100ms;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#scoreContainer {
  margin: 1000px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  /* display: grid; */
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center; */
  font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game1styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="Ania JS/Ania game1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to find out the mistake I'm making to display the image inside the button, please help me with that. Thank You.

Comment: The path is not valid !!  Right-click on your page in the browser and **Copy Image Address** then paste it and check if it's valid.

Comment: The image inside the button wouldn't be displayed if path is not valid. When the button is clicked, I wanted the images inside the buttons to be displayed, but the clickChoice function doesn't seem to be right. Could you help me with that.